# Mostrar información en modal de bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal

Estoy haciendo un sitio de recetas de cocina, cuando realizo el listado de las recetas, escribo el nombre de la receta y tres botones más, unos para ver la información, otros para editarla y el otro para borrarla.

En el caso de la edición y del borrado es fácil porque los paso por parámetros y los abro en una nueva página php, pero en el caso de Ver, la idea seria que lo abra con una ventana modal, pero lo que no se es como pasar o poner el $row['codigo'] paraque en el modal se pueda hacer el select en la base de datos y mostrar la información.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Ver </button>  
        
        <a href="edit_recetas.php?nik='.$row['codigo'].'" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <a href="index.php?aksi=delete&nik='.$row['codigo'].'" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm(\'Esta seguro de borrar los datos '.$row['nombre'].'?\')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <button class="massshow-modal btn btn-success" 
                data-nombre="4der5"
                data-descripcion="como esta tu">
    
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Ver</button>

<button class="massshow-modal btn btn-success" 
                data-nombre="45"
                data-descripcion="1434_34"

    >
    
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Ver</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
           <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required/>
            <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '.massshow-modal', function() {   
     $('#nombre').val($(this).data('nombre'));
     $('#descripcion').val($(this).data('descripcion'));
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

aquí le dejo un buen ejemplo de como puede mostrar la información de un modal, copie el código y ejecútelo y hay me va a mostrar los datos

el div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
```

corresponde el modal que va que yo quiero declara

y el codigo  `$('#myModal').modal('show');` me dice que me muestre el siguiente modal

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <button class="massshow-modal btn btn-success" 
                data-nombre="45"
                data-descripcion="como esta tu">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Ver</button>

<button class="massshow-modal btn btn-success" 
                data-nombre="45"
                data-descripcion="1434_34"

    >

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Ver</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
           <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required/>
            <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '.massshow-modal', function() {   
     $('#nombre').val($(this).data('nombre'));
     $('#descripcion').val($(this).data('descripcion'));
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que quieres necesitas usar JavaScript o Jquery.

Podrías tener un input oculto donde guardes el valor de ***$row['codigo']*** y después recuperarlo con JavaScript o Jquery.

Luego mediante ***ajax*** hacer una consulta y rellenar los campos de la modal.

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear una tablas asi

```
<?php
$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
etc...

include './conexion.php';
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE codigo = 
'$codigo';") or die(mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

}
?>
<script languaje="javascript">
location.href = "../nombre este archivo.php";
</script>
<?php
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

de verdad espero que os sirva

Comment: Podrias explicar  mas tu respuesta para que se aceptada